# static storage class in C

Tags: c, storage-class-specifier

If I declare a static variable in a function in this manner:

`static int i=4;
//custom code
i++;`

it works as it is supposed to, i.e. it maintains the variable value across function calls.

But if I declare it as follows:

`static int i;
i=4;
//custom code
i++;`

it is not maintaining the value across calls and works like a local variable.

Does this mean that 'i' is not a static variable anymore inside the function? what is the reason behind this behaviour?

A similar situation occurs with the `extern` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialization (first code) is not the same as assignment (second code).

In the second code, it does remain its value across function calls as well, but then it's assigned to another value `4`.

```
void foo()
{
    static int i;
    // i remains its value from the last call
    i=4;    //here it's assigned to 4
    //custom code
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It saves it's value across function calls, but when you assign a variable like this:

```
static int i=4;
```

it is assigned only once. When you do it like this:

```
static int i;
i=4;
```

it means: 'create a variable once. Assign `4` to it every time the function runs.'.

A small demo: [ideone](http://ideone.com/RqJ6UQ)

Answer (score 0):

```
In your second code statement you are overwriting the value of i. 
that is why it seems to work like local variable. 
It is not though.
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialization and assignment both are different
In the first step you are initializing by assigning
in the second you are assigning

If a variable is static initialization is done once and assignment may be multiple time

That is the reason in the first case the value is persistent b/n different calls